# How to reference and dereference a hash of hashes for subroutines in Perl

Tags: perl, reference, subroutine, dereference, hash-of-hashes

Does anyone know how to dereference a hash of hashes so that I can use it in my subroutine. As you can see, I'm having trouble accessing my Hash of Hashes data structure in my subroutine.

```
my $HoH_ref = \%HoH;     # reference the hash of hashes

for(@sorted) {
print join("\t", $_, get_num($_, $HoH_ref))
}

sub get_num {
    my ($foo) = shift;
    my $HoH_ref = shift;
    my %HoH = %{$HoH_ref};    # dereference the hash of hashes
    my $variable = %HoH{$foo}{'name'};
    # do stuff
    return;
    }
```

I'm getting an syntax error on the second to last line `%HoH{$protein}{'degree'}` near `%HoH{` and the hash of hashes is not recognizing `$protein` key from `%HoH`. I'm getting the error message: `Global symbol "$protein" requires explicit package name`. thanks

Comment: It is hard to tell without see the entire script but I think you want `$HoH{$foo}{'name'}` instead of `%HoH{$foo}{'name'}`.

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax to access a hash element is `$hash{KEY}`, not `%hash{KEY}`.

```
my %HoH = %{$HoH_ref};
my $variable = $HoH{$foo}{name};
               ^
               |
```

But copying the entire hash is silly. Use

```
my $variable = $HoH_ref->{$foo}{name};
```